# Android: How to use onActivityResult from activity object?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have a helper class that takes an activity and does stuff with it.

```
public MyClass(AppCompatActivity activity, Callbacks callbacks) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.callbacks = callbacks;
}
```

What I do in this class is basically call other activies/libraries in a certain order and use the results. I put this in a helper class so that I can easily reuse the code.

---

**This is the problem I have:**

With the new `ActivityResultLauncher` it's easy to "modularize" what I need:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> chooseImageLauncher = activity.registerForActivityResult(...);

...


Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
chooseImageLauncher.launch(intent);
```

And in the implementation of `chooseImageLauncher` I do whatever I want next. In this case, I will call a library.

The problem is that the library I'm calling was last updated 2020 and doesn't provide a method for an `ActivityResultLauncher`. It only supports the old way with `onActivityResult`:

```
MyLibrary.init().start(activity);
```

And the result can be caught like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MyLibrary.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I can only implement that in each activity itself. How can I implement here?

Comment: If you have a library that forces you to use deprecated APIs, then you don't really have a choice, do you? You either stop using that library or continue to use the deprecated APIs it forces you to use.

Comment: I think you got the question wrong. I don't care if I use `onActivityResult` or `ActivityResultLauncher`, I just need to get it to work, i.e. getting the results of the library in the helper class.

Comment: If the library requires that you override `onActivityResult` in your Activity to get a result, then you have no choice: that's the only place the old, deprecated APIs deliver the results to. You can't modularize code built on those deprecated APIs - that's one of the main reasons they are deprecated in the first place.

Comment: I now worked around it: I made the Helper Class an AppCompatActivity itself, called everything from there, and used `onActivityResult` from itself. I made the activity invisible/transparent and added `finish()` calls where needed. I guess there's a better solution, but it works. Another idea might be to make HelperClass extend AppCompatActivity and in `onActivityResult` handle the results and then call `super.onActivityResult()`. Then just make the activity you need the functionality in extend HelperClass. Haven't tested it though

Answer (score 0):

You could add a private class inside your helper class that extends Activity. This way you can still catch the value emitted by your library.

```
private class MyLibraryActivityWrapper extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void init() {
        MyLibrary.init().start(activity);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == MyLibrary.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        }
    }
}
```